# session.Save forces insert on id 0 relation objects - Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

So yeah, I'm trying to insert a new entity on my database, which has some foreign keys pointing to auxiliar tables, which in this case shouldn't be updated.

It has 8 total foreign keys, which are all working but for one which has to be id = 0;

```
using (var session = FluentNHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
   using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
   {
      try
      {
         session.SaveOrUpdate(p);
         transaction.Commit();
         return p;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
      }
    }
}
```

I guess there's no need to show the structure of the entity itself but for the map of the object:

```
References(x => x.Jerarquia).Column("TCODJERARQUIALIN").Cascade.All().Not.Nullable();
References(x => x.Conformidad).Column("TCODCONFORMIDADL").Cascade.All().Not.Nullable();
References(x => x.Tramitacion).Column("TCODESTADOTRAMIT").Cascade.All().Not.Nullable();
References(x => x.SistemaReferencia).Column("TCODSISTEMAREFER").Cascade.All().Not.Nullable();
References(x => x.Vigencia).Column("TCODVIGENCIALINE").Cascade.All().Not.Nullable();
References(x => x.CategoriaGeometrica).Column("TCODCATGEOMETRIC").Cascade.All().Not.Nullable();
References(x => x.Territorio1).Column("TCODIDTERRITORI1").Cascade.All().Not.Nullable();
References(x => x.Territorio2).Column("TCODIDTERRITORI2").Cascade.All().Not.Nullable();
```

Structure of the rest of the mappings comes to be like this, no matter which the related item is:

```
Id(x => x.TCODJERARQUIA).Column("TCODJERARQUIA").Not.Nullable();
Map(x => x.TTEXDESCJERAR_ES).Column("TTEXDESCJERAR_ES").Not.Nullable();
Map(x => x.TTEXDESCJERAR_EU).Column("TTEXDESCJERAR_EU").Not.Nullable();
Table("TARLLJERAR");
```

To sum it up, if one of the foreign key items is id = 0, it wont set the foreign key but will insert a new item on aux table

How can i solve this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand how an ID can be 0. Is it pointing to an entity with the same id or should this be just empty?

Comment: ID of that row (in BD) is 0, hence (i guess) Fluent is detecting it as if it were an item to add, or something like that :S Because of id being 0